# Flash to html5 converter

Tags: html, flash

I am wondering if anyone knows a way to convert flash into html5. I have no idea I am after creating a flash to html5 web application. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You best choice is Tools For Create JS. It's a Flash Professional plugin that allows you to publish flash content to HTML5.

Link: http://www.adobe.com/products/flash/flash-to-html5.html

Also, take a look at the tutorial by Lee Brimelow:

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=174 --- Flash Toolkit for CreateJS

and

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=172 --- Converting ActionScript to JavaScript

As you will see you can do some amazing stuff using Flash Professional just to make a design/art but you'll also see that you'll have to do some coding as well, so it's not a perfect solution.

If you're interested in creating games/applications that will run in Flash (.swf), JavaScript (.html, .js) and most other popular platform, your best bet is to look into Haxe (http://haxe.org). Moreover it's framework OpenFL, that uses Haxe as programming language (http://www.openfl.org). Haxe is a different language, but it's 98% similar to action script, so you'll have an easy time to get started.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as answered if I did answer your question. I am greedy for the reputation thingy you know :D

Answer (score 4):

Use "Google Swiffy" library
which is more efficient than any other tool or library
It also has plugin which can be installed in your flash
or can be directly use online version

Thankyou

Comment: Swiffy was shut down July 1, 2016